# Windows universal application Deployment issue

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I am trying to install package programatically. And i need to create the Package manager instance. It's throwing E_ACESSDENIED!

```
Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager packageManager = new Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager();
```

Exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from 
HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'
```

I am in the administrative account. What's wrong with this API?

Comment: Added the capability to manage package in the manifest following below answer and it worked :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721521/findpackagesforcurrentpublisher-in-windows-10-for-pc

Answer (score 1):

You will need to declare the 'packageQuery' and/or 'packageManagement' capability (depending on which PackageManager APIs you need to use) in your manifest in order to create a PackageManager instance from a UWP app.

If you are planning to submit this app to the Windows Store, your account/app will need to get approved for using this restricted capability, otherwise the Store submission will get rejected.

Comment: packageManagement or packageQuery? The packageManagement worked for me.

Comment: Depends on what PM APIs you are using. If you are not using FindPackage* APIs you may not need to declare 'packageQuery'. I'll edit my answer.